# Computing $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\lfloor{\sqrt{n+1}}\rfloor-\lfloor{\sqrt{n}}\rfloor}{n}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I would like to prove the existence and the exact value of the following series:

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\lfloor{\sqrt{n+1}}\rfloor-\lfloor{\sqrt{n}}\rfloor}{n}$$

Comment: Hint: When is $\lfloor\sqrt{n+1}\rfloor \neq \lfloor \sqrt{n}\rfloor$?

Comment: Think about the first quite a few terms. It is easy to write them down explicitly.  You should get something familiar, a famous series.

Comment: @Chon I'm guessing by exact you mean closed form, right?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If $ n+1 $ is a square,  $\lfloor \sqrt{n+1} \rfloor=\sqrt{n+1} $

$$ 0<\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}<1$$

So: $$ \sqrt{n+1}-1<\sqrt{n}<\sqrt{n+1} $$

So: $$ \lfloor \sqrt{n} \rfloor= \sqrt{n+1}-1$$

$$ \lfloor{\sqrt{n+1}}\rfloor-\lfloor{\sqrt{n}}\rfloor=1 $$

I have proved:

$n+1$ is a square $\Longrightarrow \lfloor{\sqrt{n+1}}\rfloor \neq \lfloor{\sqrt{n}}\rfloor$

Now I must show that

$ \lfloor{\sqrt{n+1}}\rfloor \neq \lfloor{\sqrt{n}}\rfloor \Longrightarrow $ $n+1$ is a square

If $ n+1$ is not a square:

If $ n $ is a square, $\lfloor \sqrt{n} \rfloor=\sqrt{n}$.
 As
 $$ \sqrt{n+1}-1<\sqrt{n}<\sqrt{n+1} $$

$ \lfloor \sqrt{n+1} \rfloor= \sqrt{n} $

So: $  \lfloor \sqrt{n+1} \rfloor= \lfloor \sqrt{n} \rfloor $

If $ n $ is not a square, there exists $a\in \mathbb{N} $ such that

$$ a^2<n<n+1<(a+1)^2$$

So:

$$ a<\sqrt{n}<\sqrt{n+1}<a+1$$

So : 
$$  \lfloor \sqrt{n+1} \rfloor= \lfloor \sqrt{n} \rfloor $$

Finally:

$n+1$ is a square $\Longleftrightarrow \lfloor{\sqrt{n+1}}\rfloor \neq \lfloor{\sqrt{n}}\rfloor$

So: $$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\lfloor{\sqrt{n+1}}\rfloor-\lfloor{\sqrt{n}}\rfloor}{n}=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2-1}=\cdots=\frac{3}{4}$$

Comment: Good. You could have saved some space. For example, if $n+1$ is not a square, then there exists an integer $a$ such that $a^2\le n<n+1<(a+1)^2$. So you don't need to consider $n$ a square, not a square separately.

Comment: You are right, thank you!

Comment: Your last sum should start at $2$, not $1$.

Answer (score 5):

As all terms of the given series $s=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ are $\geq0$ we may collect them in packets and write
$$s=\sum_{r=1}^\infty\left(\sum\nolimits_{r^2\leq n<(r+1)^2} a_n\right)\ .$$
Note that in the inner sum only the last term, corresponding to $n=(r+1)^2-1$, is nonzero and has the value $${1\over(r+1)^2-1}={1\over (r+2) r}={1\over2}\Bigl({1\over r}-{1\over r+2}\Bigr)\ .$$
It follows that the outer sum is a telescoping series, and we obtain
$$s={1\over 2}\sum_{r=1}^\infty \Bigl({1\over r}-{1\over r+2}\Bigr)={1\over2}\bigl(1+{1\over2}\Bigr)={3\over4}\ .$$

Answer (score 4):

Work on Thomas Andrews's hint (That is a very good hint)

Let me give a following hint

$$ \left\lfloor \sqrt{(3+1)}  \right\rfloor = 2,   \hspace{3pt} \left\lfloor \sqrt{(2+1)}  \right\rfloor = 1, \text{ why?} $$

$$ \left\lfloor \sqrt{(8+1)}  \right\rfloor = 3,  \hspace{3pt} \left\lfloor \sqrt{(7+1)}  \right\rfloor = 2, \text{ why?} $$

Try working towards these observed values, and in general for what values are they not equal?

The answer is $$\frac{3}{4}$$